# Iterate and change values in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have costs in several currencies in one column. I want to make a new column that will convert all the costs to USD.

This is what I did:

```
for i in range(len(df)) :
if(df[i]['Currency'] == 'Botswana Pula(P)'):
    df[i]['new cost'] = df[i]['Average Cost for two'] * 0.095
...
```

and so on for the other currencies.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: This is not working... I want to know what is the right way of doing it

Comment: You should provide working/trouble code with sample data and the expected output. That helps people picture your problem a lot easier.